# Haskell: Problem using map on abstract data types

Tags: list, haskell, dictionary, types, compiler-errors

Straight to the point, the type declarations are as follow;

```
type Pnt = (Int, Int)
type Image = Array Point Int
type Pixels = [Int]
type Dims = (Int, Int)
type Block = (Point,Pixels)
```

What am trying to do is to get an `Image`, and from that image obtain a particular block of pixels at position `Pnt` with a width and length `Dims`. When working with only one point is fine, no problems or whatsoever;

```
takeAblock :: Image -> Dims -> Pnt -> Block
takeAblock i (w,h) (x,y) = ((x,y),  [i!(u,v) |  v <-[y..y + h - 1], u <- [x..x + w - 1]])
```

However when trying to get multiple points I'm finding myself stuck on how what I believed to be a correct implementation, however the compiler does not seem to agree with me

```
takeManyBlocks :: Image -> Dims -> [Pnt] -> [Block]
takeManyBlocks i d ps = takeAblock i d (map ps)
                                        where ps (x,y) = x  // Error
```

And the error is the following:

> ```
> Couldn't match expected type `Pnt'
>        against inferred type `[(t, t1)] -> [t]'
> In the third argument of `takeAblock', namely `(map ps)'
> In the expression: takeAblock i d (map ps)
> In the definition of `takeAblock':
>     takeAblock i d ps
>                 = takeAblock i d (map ps)
>                 where
>                     ps (x, y) = x
> ```

I really cant understand why this is not working, I even tried `map (*1) ps` to check whether the lack of a stated function was the problem, but nothing, the compile error remains the same. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Hint: map takes a function and a list.  What are you passing it?

Comment: Owch, owch owch.  Please don't shadow variable names (note the `takeManyBlocks` argument is named `ps` in addition to the where clause defining `ps`).  This makes it hard to even talk about what you are doing.  Use warnings on the compiler to bring these things to your attention.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lack of the function is indeed the problem, but not the way you seem to think; something like `map (*1) ps` is a no-op (for `ps` a list of numbers, at least).  What you really want is something along the lines of `map (takeAblock i d) ps`; the thing you want to map over the list is the first parameter to `map`, not sitting somewhere on the other side of it.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want something like:

```
takeManyBlocks i d ps = [takeAblock i d p | p <- ps]
```